# Android - ListActivity to Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i have this code;

```
private void displayResultList() {
    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
```

for use that i need

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
```

but with this when i use

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

i get error (line 25 is "setContentView(R.layout.main);)

```
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031): Process: com.example.app.arr, PID: 1031
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app.arr/com.example.app.arr.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.example.app.arr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-26 04:47:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1031):     ... 11 more
```

my question is who can i do some thing like "displayResultList" when i using "extends Activity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ***ListActivity*** then in your xml file just change this for ListView id

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and in your Activity call this

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

If you are using ***Activity*** then just find id of your ListView in your java file by

```
Listview mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

and set adapter for that

```
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a reference to a ListView in your layout

```
Listview mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

Then call things like

```
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is described in the following line.

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Since you are using `ListActivity` your `ListView` view must have id in the name 'android.R.id.list'. Code is fine otherwise.

So you need a respective change in your `xml` file.

**EDIT**

You can put the following code in your `ListView`

**EDIT II**

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Try calling the following after `setContentView()`

```
ListView listview = getListView();
```

Comment: you mean and listview with android:id="@+id/list"?